# Bounding 0-1 matrix with k unique rows

Tags: optimization, np-complete, clustering, upper-bound

**Problem Statement:**
Suppose that I have a $0-1$ matrix $A$ (all of the entries are $0$ or $1$). I wish to find the tightest upper bound with $k$ many unique rows. To be more precise, let S denote the set of $0-1$ matrices $B$ such that it only has $k$ unique rows, $A_{ij} \leq B_{ij}$ for all $i$ and $j$.
Find
$$\min_{B \in S} ||A - B||$$

**Example:**
Suppose $k = 2$ and
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the optimal matrix $B$ is
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Since $B$ only has $2$ distinct rows, $A \leq B$, and $||A - B|| = 3$ is minimized.

**Question 1:**
This problem reminds of the minimum $k$-union, set-union, and other NP-complete problems. Is this problem an NP-complete optimization problem?

**Question 2:**
Is there an efficient way to obtain *approximately* optimal matrix $B \in S$? Instead of minimizing $||A - B||$, can we get close to the minimum possible value?

So far, I have tried to cluster each row of matrix $A$ using k-means. Then within each cluster $i$, I tried to construct a vector $v_i$. Where $j^{th}$ entry of $v_i$ is $1$ if at least p-percent of the vectors in cluster $i$ has $j^{th}$ entry to be $1$. The vectors $v_i$ served as initial potential guess for possible rows of the matrix $B$. Then I used greedy algorithm. This has decent performance, but it's not great.

Comment: Which matrix norm does $\| \cdot \|$ represent?  Can you [edit] the question to state that?

Comment: Apparently it's the $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_1$ norm

Comment: $||\cdot ||_p$ for any $p \geq 0$ results in same minimization problem. But $||\cdot||_1$ is probably the easiest to think about.